# How to SaveAs to an HTML email using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to open an email template, make some changes and save (.msg) to a folder.

Everything goes right except the email is sometimes saved as a "Plain Text" body format, not "HTML" format.

```vb
Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TheTemplateLocation)
'''''Some actions here
oItem.SaveAs SaveToLocation, olMSGUnicode
oItem.Close olDiscard
Set oItem = Nothing
```

I tried changing `olMSGUnicode` to `olMSG` or even deleting it, but nothing changed.
I also tried `oItem.Save` but the mail was automatically saved to the "Draft" folder, which is not useful for me.

However, this issue does not always happen, sometimes it's saved as a correct "HTML" version. But I really want to make sure this issue won't happen anymore.

Comment: Have you tried to set `BodyFormat` property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat. Try setting it to `olFormatHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use late binding code outside of Outlook, eg in Excel then

the constants `olMSGUnicode` and `olDiscard` do not exist in Excel as they are Outlook constants. You can easily see that by using `Option Explicit`.

So either you need to define them in Excel first to be able to use them or use their numeric value instead. Therefore have a look at the [OlSaveAsType enumeration](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olsaveastype) and the [OlInspectorClose enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olinspectorclose).

Also you might want to use `olHTML` instead.

So declare them like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const olDiscard As Long = 1          ' Changes to the document are discarded.
Public Const olPromptForSave As Long = 2    ' User is prompted to save documents.
Public Const olSave As Long = 0             ' Documents are saved.

Public Const olDoc As Long = 4              ' Microsoft Office Word format (.doc)
Public Const olHTML As Long = 5             ' HTML format (.html)
Public Const olICal As Long = 8             ' iCal format (.ics)
Public Const olMHTML As Long = 10           ' MIME HTML format (.mht)
Public Const olMSG As Long = 3              ' Outlook message format (.msg)
Public Const olMSGUnicode As Long = 9       ' Outlook Unicode message format (.msg)
Public Const olRTF As Long = 1              ' Rich Text format (.rtf)
Public Const olTemplate As Long = 2         ' Microsoft Outlook template (.oft)
Public Const olTXT As Long = 0              ' Text format (.txt)
Public Const olVCal As Long = 7             ' VCal format (.vcs)
Public Const olVCard As Long = 6            ' VCard format (.vcf)

Public Sub Example()
    Dim oOutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    Set oItem = oOutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TheTemplateLocation)
    '''''Some actions here
    
    oItem.SaveAs SaveToLocation, olMSGUnicode
    oItem.Close olDiscard
    
    Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or use their values directly

```
oItem.SaveAs SaveToLocation, 9
oItem.Close 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, it looks very successful!